# What's the best practice for passing data in React Native navigation: ID or JSON object for performance?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a React Native app, and I have a question regarding the parameters passed via navigation. For instance, if I have a list of clients, and when I click on a client to view their details, should I pass the client's ID and then fetch the JSON data via an API call, or should I directly pass the 'client' JSON as a parameter? In terms of performance and best practices, which approach is recommended?

Comment: Re-fetching data that you already have certainly seems unnecessary, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transferring only the ID through navigation is a more efficient way to transfer data. In the case of transferring large amounts of data, such as complete customer information, the application itself may slow down due to performance and memory utilization issues.

To ensure better performance and adherence to best practices, it is recommended to pass only the customer ID through navigation and then retrieve JSON data through an API call for each individual customer.